# Currency objects being changed to a decimal.Decimal instance is used

Tags: python, excel, error-handling, currency, currency-formatting

I am having an issue with my program not being able to handle currency objects that I am pulling from excel spreadsheets. The code runs and does what I want other than this error with changing the currencies. Here is the error that shows up when I execute the code. Are there recommendations for this?

> FutureWarning: Currency objects will soon be changed so a decimal.Decimal instance is used.
>    (set pythoncom.**future_currency** to get these objects now.)

Here is the code that I am running:

```
import sys, os, win32com.client, glob
from win32com.client import constants
xl = Excel_Document()

headerlist = ['STUDYDES','STUDYDES2','EVENTTYPE','AssessmentSOLUTIONTYPE','AssessmenFDNS-TERMINATION','SOLUTIONTYPE','FDNS-TERMINATION','GROUP','SCENARIO','ProviderOASISReservation','CustomerName','RequestedStart_Date']

ListofData = []
Data = []
counter = 1
xlslist = glob.glob('*tblFacilityLog*.xls')



for xls in xlslist:
    headers = {}
    sortedvalues = []
    output = {}
    print 'Opening Workbook: ',xls
    xl.openWorkbook(xls)

    sheetdata = xl.getSheetData('tblAllFacilityLog')
    xl.closeWorkbook()

    for row in sheetdata:
        sortedvalues = []
        for header in headerlist:
            if header in sheetdata[0]:
                output[header] = row[sheetdata[0].index(header)]
            else:
                output[header] = "'None'"

        for header in headerlist:
            sortedvalues.append(output[header])

        Data.append(sortedvalues)

    ListofData.append(Data)

print 'Building Workbook'
print len(Data)
print len(ListofData)

xl.addWorkbook()
xl.addWorksheet("tblFacilityLog9")
xl.selectSheet("tblFacilityLog9")


beginrow = 1
lastrow = beginrow + len(Data)
#xl.pasteData(headerlist, startcol = beginrow, startrow = beginrow, endcol = len(headerlist), endrow = 1)

for Data in ListofData:
    xl.pasteData(Data, startcol = 1, startrow = 1, endcol = len(headerlist), endrow = lastrow)

xl.saveWorkbook("CombinedLog")
xl.closeWorkbook()
xl.closeApp()
```

Comment: What part of this code is dealing with currency objects?

Comment: Probably what he is reading from the excel spreadsheet.

Comment: use xlrd ... thats my two cents... unless you absolutely need `xlsm` or some type other than `xls`

Comment: The error pops up after the first workbook opens and then it runs through the rest of the code with no problems. This code is opening multiple workbooks and combines certain parts of certain sheets.

I knew I would get the xlrd suggestion when I posted this question. I tried that but I am not familiar with it and this method seemed more straightforward to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means: if it works now ignore the Warning. If it you will not update the pythoncom module then you have no problem. If you want to use a newer version of pythoncom soon then you can try out the new functionality by doing

```
import pythoncom
pythoncom.__future_currency__ = True # I guess it is True
```

This is my understanding of the error.